# Why did this question about framework comparisons get closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed, not-constructive

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051755/ember-angularjs-and-knockout-js-comparison) question, to my surprise, was closed.

I honestly have no idea why. The question fits perfectly within the FAQ, is not particularly subjective (nor is the answer), and it's generally good content.

From the FAQ:

> [I]f your question generally covers practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Here's the kicker though:

> [I]f your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

And I think that question fits very reasonably within "I would like others to explain the difference between [blank] and [blank] to me."

It's also *definitely* not [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). So, why was it closed? I removed the subjective-sounding bits at the end before it had enough close votes, but that apparently didn't do much. If good content like that is being closed because of the "rules," then shouldn't that be an indication that something else is wrong?

Comment: What's the actual practical problem to be solved? It's a typical broad comparison question...

Comment: @YannisRizos: It's not overly broad at all. It's asking for differences between three similar frameworks (and they're all within the same language).

Comment: Again: What's the _actual practical problem_? `I don't have time to compare the frameworks myself` is _not_ a programming problem.

Comment: @YannisRizos: We could apply the same reasoning to all questions. `I don't have time to experiment further in fixing my code.` is also not a problem, then?

Comment: `I don't have time to experiment further in fixing my code.` is also not a programming problem. `I have this problem, tried this and that, didn't work, and I don't know what else to do` is a programming problem.

Comment: @YannisRizos: The actual percentage of questions that show effort in trying to fix it themselves might as well be 1%. `I don't have time to experiment further in fixing my code` is about the same argument used by everyone. Most of the time, just looking up some documentation would fix it. We keep all those questions, the dupes and "not a real question" questions open but close the ones with good content? That's twisted and senseless.

Comment: I'm explaining the closure, feel free to disagree with my explanation. That doesn't make it wrong ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos: Nor does it make it right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of all of the [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) I've seen on Stack Overflow, the one you linked might actually be useful to software developers.  Yet it still fails the ["Good Subjective, Bad Subjective"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) test. Why? Because, in the end, it amounts to "Which one is your favorite?"

Good questions of this variety don't ask for a contrast and compare essay; instead they focus on *how to choose:*

> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> ```
> Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?
> A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
> ```
>
> Here’s another way to ask:
>
> ```
> Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos? 
> A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
>
>     a fast lens (2.0 at least)
>     reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
>     the biggest sensor available
>
> The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.
> ```

That, in a nutshell, is the difference between a good subjective question, and one that's merely a Big List of Things.  Kudos to AlexG for taking the time to post a constructive answer, instead of "I liek this."

Comment: Well, it doesn't really ask for the best or which is better. It just asks for the comparison. Any choosing beyond that is up to the asker. By the way, thank you for posting the only straightforward answer that takes into account the fact that it's not a Gorilla vs. Shark question. :P

Comment: @Purmou keep in mind he's trying to teach you so you learn, but I imagine he would've closed the question as it was. I've been around Robert long enough to have seen that he is both of those.

Comment: @jcolebrand: if that's the case, then he knows exactly how to get someone to listen. :P

Answer (score 18):

This is a question about pros and cons, features and drawbacks, strengths and weaknesses.

It's not chest beating subjective, but it is bullet list comparative. What's the difference? Nothing much other than delivery and fervour. And the only solution to that is a matrix of whatitgots and whatitdonts.

In bold essence, a Gorilla, a Shark and a Pterodactyl meet with a jumbo jar of Vaseline.

Comment: Thanks for the image.

Comment: But what's the problem with "a matrix of whatitgots and whatitdonts?"

Comment: A matrix isn't part of a Q&A pair, but the callsheet pushing you into starting something. It's for when you haven't actually started to program and want to work out what pen is best for writing notes on, or what chair will help you do work in. Pick one, stumble on its logic and need assistance, then we'll have a question to answer.  @pur

Comment: @random: I see your point. Do you have a thing for cryptic answers? :P

Comment: This is "classic random."

Answer (score 6):

What's the point of comparing the frameworks? The answer is very simple, to pick one. But pick one for what? What's the OP building and why do they need a framework? If we knew that, the question could be useful, but as it is it's *not* about an actual practical problem.

The question is a typical Gorilla vs Shark question, broad comparisons simply don't work with the Q&A format as their only answer is "it depends", and that's not useful to anyone. Ironically the [single answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052831/99456) to the question concludes (emphasis mine):

> I don't think there's a clear winner there. **Depending on which factors you favor**, you may feel more comfortable with one of the 3.

If only we knew those factors...

Comment: But...it's not broad. They are three similar frameworks. It's Chimp vs. Human.

Comment: @Purmou I never said it's broad, I said `broad comparison` in the sense that the comparison itself doesn't have specific parameters. It's Chimp vs. Human, but comparing what exactly? Cognitive abilities, physical strength, chest hair?

Answer (score 3):

The first revision of the question (the only revision made from the OP) is the following one:

> As far as I know, these are the most famous js mvc frameworks that are declarative and imperative. I've been learning emberjs for a couple of weeks. My notes about it is that it is very promising and I love it, while on the other and it is immature and of course has documentation shortage. Very recently I knew about knockoutjs and angularjs. Their documentations seem very appealing, and they seem to do almost the same tasks that identify ember: data binding, templating, auto ui refresh, and can live with other js libraries (most importantly jquery).
>   There are a couple of comparisons about these frameworks, but they compare them against other frameworks that are not declarative. But there is no comparison that compares them as rivals.
>   I hope the community here can recommend a best choice among these three or maybe another one that I am not aware of.

There isn't an explicit question. The OP states some facts, writes his opinions, but he is not asking any question.
The implicit question could be:

- Is there any comparison between these frameworks that can help me deciding which one to use?
- May you compare those frameworks, giving me the information I need?
- Which framework should I use?
- Which framework would you use?

I would have closed it as not a real question, but I think it is also not constructive. If the user asked which framework to use in a specific case, the question would have been acceptable, but it doesn't seem acceptable as it is.

Even in the case the OP is really asking if there are comparisons that include the information s/he wants, I would close it as not constructive. Questions about online resources are not generally good answers, considering that new resource can make obsolete, or less preferable, existing resources suggested in the answers.

If the user is interested in knowing which framework should be used, the question should make clear in which specific case the framework is meant to be used. Also in this case, I am not sure the question is constructive. The framework I should use could depend from external factors, or my experience with other similar frameworks; there isn't an answer that is valid in every case.

Comment: ...The question is "what are the differences and similarities between x and y?" which is usually implied when you're saying the word "comparison."

Comment: That is not different from the "May you compare those frameworks, giving me the information I need?" I supposed implied in that question. Anyway, questions should be explicit, not implicit.

Comment: I think it's pretty explicit if the title says "Compare these for me."

Comment: That is not the actual title. The actual title could imply the user is asking for existing comparisons.

Comment: @Purmou - The thing is, the asker didn't ask for a comparison. The question, before your edit, asked for the community to blindly make a decision for the asker instead. `"I hope the community here can recommend a best choice..."`. See [Robert Harvey's response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144545/155826) for more clarification on how this could have been asked.